# Incremental build VSTS for files changed only (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build and release pipeline for Wordpress php files, but I only want to create a build for the files changed in source control. I am not using a Visual Studio Build task as this does not apply in case of php files I guess.

**Here is how the pipeline is configured:**
Currently under the **build** I am using publish artifacts only from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` and under the **release** pipeline I am copying those artifacts to the website using FTP upload.

Since the amount of files is larger than 10K,

> I want it to only build files that have changed and publish those
>   instead of the whole directory again.

**How do I achieve that within the build as the release will automatically pick files up based on the artifacts.**

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the feature in VSTS that can just pick files up based on the previous artifacts.

You can refer to these ways to achieve it:

1. Create XML file that stores the last upload/publish information of each files (e.g. file name, date time, changeset/commit version).
2. Create a PowerShell script file that included the logical to compare files ([get files metadata](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items#get-item-metadata-for) and compare with that XML file) and copy updated files to specific folder
3. Publish the files in that folder