# How to build and release only the modified files using CI/CD pipeline in VSTS?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am currently in the process of architecting a CI/CD pipeline using VSTS. Whenever a developer commits his changes to the solution in his local visual studio and syncs the changes with remote repository, it triggers the build and release process automatically. How do I release only the files modified by the developer to Azure platform? Is there a feature in VSTS to handle delta deployment?

Comment: where are you publishing to? I believe if you are publishing to WebApps kudu knows how to do that.

Comment: I am publishing the artifacts to an existing data factory in azure portal

Answer (score 1):

VSTS build/release does not support build/release only changed files since only build/release changed files not always meaningful and can’t archeive what the project intend to release (such as the config file only changed in a commit).

But you can change your build definition to meet your requirement. Use a file to record each time upload/publish files -> compare with the new committed information -> publish only changed files. More details, you can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910678/incremental-build-vsts-for-files-changed-only-wordpress).

Comment: will you able to find a solution ?