# Incremental Builds in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

is there a way to build and deploy incremental changes instead of the entire Repos after every change? I'm looking to deploy only changed items instead of the entire project.

Comment: What kind of project are you building that allows you to only deploy changed items?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is that break your solution to multiple projects and create particular build pipeline for each one.

In the case that you need **Continuous Integration**, you should specify triggers for each build by an individual path of the solution (.e.g Path specification = /project1). This will lead you to break down your repository to multiple build definitions and release pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910678/incremental-build-vsts-for-files-changed-only-wordpress) :

There isn’t the feature in VSTS that can just pick files up based on the previous artifacts.

You can refer to these ways to achieve it:

1.Create XML file that stores the last upload/publish information of each files (e.g. file name, date time, changeset/commit version).

2.Create a PowerShell script file that included the logical to compare files (get files metadata and compare with that XML file) and copy updated files to specific folder

3.Publish the files in that folder